# Returning only First value in XSDK From HLS IP Instead of number series

Tags: c, sdk, vivado-hls

Just start learning HLS and XSDk.  Currently I am working with number series.

My goal is to print number series sequentially as for `N` times in Tera Terminal. While compiling the program codes, it's returning only last value.

**My code:**

```
void Numberseries1(ap_uint<32> seed, ap_uint<32> &dout) { 
    static ap_uint<32> reg[15]; 
    int result=1; 
    int i; 
    for(i=0; i < 15;i++) if (result<seed) { 
        result *= 2; reg[i] =result; dout= reg[i]; 
    } 
}
```

FOR EXAMPLE : `N=10`, it's returning only value `1024`. Instead of EXPECTED RESULT : `16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,`

What do I need to do to get "number series" to print sequentially like `16,32,64,128,256,512,1024`, in Tera Terminal.

Comment: And your code is?

Comment: void Numberseries1(ap_uint<32> seed, ap_uint<32> &dout)

      {


  static ap_uint<32> reg[15];

 int result=1;

 int i;

 for(i=0;  i < 15;i++)


  if (result<seed)
  {
            result *= 2;
            reg[i] =result;
            dout= reg[i];

        }


}

Comment: Please refer this [link](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Welcome-Join/Returning-only-Last-value-in-XSDK-From-HLS-IP-Instead-of-series/m-p/767339#M45214)